# Asterisk realtime sip.conf deny/permit

Tags: asterisk, sip

I have a realtime sip.conf using deny/permit rules. For example:
in sip.conf

```
[MyPeer]
type=peer
host=xxx.xxx.xxx.139
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=xxx.xxx.xxx.136/255.255.255.248 ;
```

in realtime i defined that

```
deny             permit
0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0  xxx.xxx.xxx.136/255.255.255.248
```

but in database i have only one column to write so i cant define second ip adress for deny/permit

```
[MyPeer]
type=peer
host=xxx.xxx.xxx.139
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=xxx.xxx.xxx.136/255.255.255.248
permit=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/255.255.255.255
```

How can i write this to realtime database?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using realtime.

You can do using res_config_realtime. i.e put config line-by-line in database(as text).

Another option is to use templates, but it is not easy too.

Answer (score 0):

After some research i found this;(I dont know how did i miss this)

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-realtime-sip/

Some options in sip.conf are OK to have multiple entries, but in a real-time database, Only one column is available. In these cases, you can add multiple values separated by semicolons. This occurs with setvar, allow/disallow, and permit/deny.

```
    deny             permit
0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0  xxx.xxx.xxx.136/255.255.255.248;xxx.xxx.xxx.137/255.255.255.248
```

Solved my problem.